# Magento 2.2.5 Fatal Error in Category and Search Page

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, magento-2.2.5

It is a fatal error that happens when I open the search or try to open any **category**.
I'm using `magento 2.2.5` with `apache 2.4` and `php 7.1`

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
   Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface in
   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
   Stack trace: #0
   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...',
   Array) #1
   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
   #2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Search/FilterMapper/ExclusionStrategy.php(90):
   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
   #3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\FilterMapper\ExclusionStrategy->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Interceptor),
   Object(Magento\Sto in
   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
   on line 111
```

Question Solved:

A co-worker helped me solve the problem. I inserted this line into the file "app/etc/di.xml":

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\ScopeResolver\IndexScopeResolver"/>
```

Comment: Have you added any module ?

Comment: @AdityaShah I installed this theme https://themeforest.net/item/artfurniture-responsive-magento-2-theme/20739210

Comment: Please run setup:upgrade command

Comment: @AdityaShah Message: "Nothing to import." Not change, same error.

Comment: I meant that run that command after uninstalling that so we can be sure about bug. Is it generation because of theme or not.

Comment: Hey, a co-worker helped me solve the problem. I inserted this line into the file "app/etc/di.xml": <preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\ScopeResolver\IndexScopeResolver"/>

Comment: That's great !! :)

Comment: @AdityaShah How do I close this question? Do I create a response or edit my question with the answer?

Comment: No, first add your solution in the answer

Comment: <preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\ScopeResolver\IndexScopeResolver"/>

Comment: There was a preference issue in `di.xml` 

> app/etc/di.xml

    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\ScopeResolver\IndexScopeResolver"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing di.xml `preference` issue.

---

> app/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\ScopeResolver\IndexScopeResolver"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue as well. It got fixed in 2.2.6 release.

[image]